# Get average values in some specific range based on spatial analysis with QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, polygon, line, spatial-statistics

I'm working on QGIS to compute average values attached to polygons around a line.

What I'd like to do is compute the average values of polygon data
within a user defined range from a line.
How would I go about doing this?

I have attached a picture below for reference:

[image]

Comment: Does the average value need to consider the area that the line buffer intersects?

Comment: can you explain how that works in your case? Let's just say you have intersected 3 features and the 'values' are 15, 10, 22 - and each feature has an area - how would area influence the values before the average is taken?

Comment: @Daichi my answer reproduces what you provided as an example, but not a weighted analysis...

Comment: @Daichi  A weighted analysis is plausible by using PyQGIS (see my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from a similar situation:

[image]

you may follow these steps:

1. Run the **Fixed Distance buffer** tool from the Processing Toolbox and create a buffer around your line using a specified distance:

[image]

2. Run the **Join attributes by location** tool from Processing Toolbox with these parameters:

[image]

You will obtain a new layer:

[image]

which stores the desired result in a new field in the Attribute Table:

[image]

Please note that this procedure only works if the values stored in the `"val"` field are formatted as float. Instead, if they are formatted as integers, even the result will be an integer (you may go beyond this issue if you previously convert your `"val"` integer field into a float field before starting my procedure).

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer ! :)
Do you know the unit of the fixed distance and meaning of "segments" ?
Also, why did you set "precision" to 3.0 ?
Now I'm processing algorithm and waiting for so long time ...

Comment: @Daichi I'm glad you appreciated and I will answer in order to your questions. The units for the fixed distance are in the same units of your project: if you are using a projected coordinate system, they will be linear (meters, feets or something like this); instead, if you are using a Geographic coordinate System, they will be degrees (you may have a look to this [link](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html) for a better clarification on how to set it).

Comment: ... This is a very important parameter because you know that 50 meters is very different from 50 degrees (I think you are using a Geographic Coordinate System and the execution time may depends from it). The "segment" number defines how many segments you will use for create the buffer: the more they are, the better will be the result (but it will increase the duration time): if you set a small number, QGIS will automatically produce a minimum number of segments that will however fit well in the most of cases.

Comment: Finally, about the Precision I think there is a typo: it should be the precision with which you want to "intersects" the layers, but I'm not sure about that: I usually set "0" without any problem. You may try varying it for viewing how the result changes.

Comment: Thank you ! I got them. I've checked the results, but I got wrong averages. The resulting average is much greater than maximum value. I followed your instruction, and the column name is "val" and its type is "Float", though ... Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: What do you see in the right lower side of the QGIS window? EPSG=?

Comment: It says EPSG:3857 (OTF). Something is wrong ?

Comment: Since layers are using EPSG:4326, so I changed it to EPSG:4326 and retried "Join attributes by location" again. But I have still wrong averages ...

Comment: BTW, in my case, I have multiple lines on a layer and some of them are connected to each other. So some padding lines overlaps. Do I have to go with different procedures ?

Comment: I think this procedure would be good for solving the issue you proposed. Please have a look to my link for a better understanding of the using of coordinate system reference because I think you are confused (you may ask a new specific question if you need more explanations). Finally, if you are encountering any particular issue (like the overlappings), I think that the best would be ask a new question where you specify the problem: only with chatting it could be impossible to help you, I'm sorry!

Comment: Thank you for your advice :) Now I could solve. What I did is deleted unnecessary columns and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

A weighted analysis is plausible by using PyQGIS. I tried it out with next shapefiles in a situation practically identical to your attached picture reference.

[image]

Next code was used at the Python Console of QGIS:

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

line = registry.mapLayersByName('line_get_average')
buffer = registry.mapLayersByName('buffer_get_average')
polygon = registry.mapLayersByName('polygon_get_average')

feats_polygon = [ feat for feat in polygon[0].getFeatures() ]

feat_buffer = buffer[0].getFeatures().next()

area_buffer = feat_buffer.geometry().area()

weighting_average = 0 

for feat in feats_polygon:
    if feat.geometry().intersects(feat_buffer.geometry()):
        area_int_buff = feat.geometry().intersection(feat_buffer.geometry()).area()
        weight_factor = area_int_buff/area_buffer
        print weight_factor, feat.attribute('val')
        weighting_average += weight_factor*feat.attribute('val')

print "weighting_average: {:.2f}".format(weighting_average)
```

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS, I got results as it's expected (see next image). Pink layer was visualized with QuickWKT plugin only for corroboration purpose.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your great work !
This is very expensive solution, so I will not use, but again, thank you !